# Titanium & Alloy - Opening a new View fails?

Tags: view, titanium, titanium-alloy

I've started working on an Alloy & Titanium project, and i need to create a new window with a new view. I've already created the files, and created the controller and view in my index.js file.

```
function onListClick(e) {
    var win = Alloy.createController('controlPage').getView();
    win.open();
}
```

This is the code that is supposed to open the new View, but...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object View has no method "open"
```

I've immediately checked the online reference, and there actually is no module "open" inside the Ti.UI.View object.

What am i supposed to do? controlPage.xml (and the relative .js and .tss file) do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

is controlPage.xml:

```
<Alloy>
  <Window>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

If it is, then you can `win.open()` since window objects have an open() method

If however, you actually have a `view` as your title, the references to Ti.UI.View, etc indicates, then you would need to add your view to a parent container.

Comment: It was a View. Switching View to Window (inside controlPage.xml) made the onClick work perfectly. Thank you for your quick answer.